# Cropper.JS uploading file size issue

Tags: angularjs, cropperjs

I am facing issue while using Cropper.JS to upload and crop the images.
Suppose I am uploading 70 kb file after using cropper tool it's size get increased and is 115KB and sometime it's also converting to MB's for some other file sizes.

Comment: How are you getting the data to send? If you are using `toBlob()` or `toDataURL()` - both of them have default mimeType "image/png" (I know right....whyyyyy.... ), so common problem is that people are just calling e.g.`toBlob(callback)` instead of `toBlob(callback, 'image/jpeg', quality)` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob btw: Edge does not support `toBlob()` but there is also a polyfill.

Answer (score 3):

If you are facing to size of cropped image problem, you can transform the cropped image to base64 and compress it by using the following code snippet (angular-cropperjs)

```
this.angularCropper.cropper.getCroppedCanvas().toDataURL('image/jpeg', (20 / 100));
```

Play with the second parameter of `toDataURL()` method to adjust ratio compression.

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL#Setting_image_quality_with_jpegs).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you should have to use newer version of cropper.

Comment: But newer version is affecting my view and output.